# Unresolved dependencies rollup

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, rollupjs

I'm doing `import file from 'file.json` in a `Vue` component, but have a challenge when I run `npm run build` to bundle it with Rollup.

It throws this error below and the file doesn't  get bundled.

[image: rollup error]

This is what I have in `rollup.config.js

```
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue'; 
import buble from 'rollup-plugin-buble';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json'

export default {
input: 'src/plugin.js',
output: {
    name: 'NaijaStatesLgas',
    exports: 'named',
},
plugins: [
    json(),
    resolve({
        jsnext: true,
        main: true,
        browser: true,
        extensions: [".js", ".json"],
        preferBuiltins: false,
    }),
    vue({
        compileTemplate: true, 
function
        }),
        buble(),
    ],
};
```

Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved it by changing `import file from 'file.json'` to `import file from './file.json'` That allows it to see the file as a local module.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on Justin's answer...

According to the documentation, found here: [Warning: "Treating [module] as external dependency"](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency)

"Rollup will only resolve relative module IDs by default. This means that an import statement like this ...
`import moment from 'moment';`
... won't result in moment being included in your bundle – instead, it will be an external dependency that is required at runtime."

That is why justin's answer of ...
`import moment from './moment';`
... works.

The link also recommends using `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` to resolve dependencies.